# How to sketch a graph for fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

I had to find fourier series for $f(x) = x$, $-\pi < x < \pi$. I found that the Fourier series for $f$ is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdot\sin(nx).$$

Now I have to sketch the graph on $\left[-3\pi,3\pi\right]$. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The fourier series is infinite, you can only graph a partial sum of the series for your interval. My guess is that it will look something like this in the first 3 terms:

[image]

See how the graph is starting to resemble f(x) = x (for x between -Pi and Pi) by the third  sum. And also notice that it is periodic with period 2*Pi

Answer (score -2):

By Fourier series , you are representing a function by an infinte sum of sinusoids. You cannot plot all of them. What you can plot is the amplitude of those sinusoids by taking index n on x-axis and magnitude on y-axis.

Comment: Could you explain me how exactly this happens? I am very confused.

Comment: Are you asking me how can we represent a function by an infinite sum of sinusoids ?  If that is your question i will give you a simple analogy .   Consider a vector .  A vector can be represented as a linear sum of orthogonal vectors (i,j,k) . The same applies to signals also . But here we extend the orthogonality to infinte number of signals . We define that orthogonal set as a set of functions which obey this property i.e integral (fx.fy) over a ,b is zero for all x,y . This set of sinusoids fall in that category and hence you can break a function into infinite number of sinusoids .